# IntelliJ suddenly showing me weird directory structure

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Accidentally deleted a project. When I re-added `Project from existing sources` without any changes to my source code, the directory structure in the project view is no longer showing individual modules/directory. Instead it looks like this:

[image]

My project is made up of multiple Maven modules.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? thanks

Comment: Open a fresh clone. This should unconfuse IntelliJ

Comment: Best is to delete the `.idea` directory and impor the full project from scratch into IDEA..